# Log4J is printing 'ALL' logs even though the level defined is 'ERROR'

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, log4j

Here is the log config for reference. I have set the log level to be ERROR but I see TRACE, INFO, DEBUG logs as well in the log file.

```
<configuration>
<turboFilter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.turbo.MarkerFilter">
    <Marker>TraceMarker</Marker>
    <OnMatch>ACCEPT</OnMatch>
</turboFilter>

<appender name="NAME" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>/file/path</file>
    <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
        <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss} [%thread] %highlight(%-5level) %cyan(%logger{35}) - [%marker] %msg %n</pattern>
    </layout>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <FileNamePattern>/Some/Pattern</FileNamePattern>
        <MaxHistory>240</MaxHistory>
        <maxFileSize>500MB</maxFileSize>
    </rollingPolicy>
</appender>

<root level="ERROR">
    <appender-ref ref="NAME" />
</root>

<logger name="com.sample.service" level="ERROR" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="NAME" />
</logger>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the root log level to **'info'**, then clean build your application and then run. Sometimes, it happens old log file is getting used during application run.

This table might be helpful to you-

[image]

Log Level- Going down the first column, you will see how the log works in each level. i.e for WARN, (FATAL, ERROR and WARN) will be visible. For OFF, nothing will be visible.